# Laravel Eloquent partial case insensitive search by term

Tags: php, laravel

supposing I have a Post model I want to search title property on Post model using a where clause where:

1) Only a part or the whole word need to match, so if I have a post titled Cooking Tutorial, searching for tut would  give me a match.

2)Search is case insensitive, so both tutorial or Tutorial may be used,

How can I do this with Eloquent?

So far I have this:

```
Post::where('title', $term)->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `LIKE` SQL comparison operator. See the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses) for other examples.

```
Post::where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$term}%")->get();
```